# API Google maps Retorno limite

Tags: google, maps

Necessito utilizar a API do google maps, porém, o retorno da requisição exibe essa mensagem.

> array(3) {   ["error_message"]=>   string(190) **"You have exceeded
>   your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a
>   key at the Google Developers Console:
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_"**
>   ["results"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["status"]=>   string(16)
>   **"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"** }

já refiz a KEY porém, esta acusando limites de requisições, sendo que no relatório do google esta com um valor abaixo de 100 diário.

o código js.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MINHA_KEYE&callback=initMap
```

já pesquisei aqui, encontrei vários posts, porém, não obtive sucessos enquanto a isso.

Comment: Você está fazendo várias requisições consecutivas, muito próximas umas das outras? Existe também um limite por segundo.

Comment: Segundo o relatório do Google, esta dando 30 requisições por minuto... o limite da API é de 100. Eu coloquei várias Key num array aleatório para resolver esse problema de requisições, porém, não teve efeito positivo.